# Zend2: Radio button list?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am creating a form and need to have a dynamic list of radio buttons as a form element. In other words, it could have 1 or 2 or how many ever different items to select from and each block of radio buttons must have it's own custom styling. Is there a way to assign a data source to a radio button form element so it will automatically build the radio button options based on the data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the [`formRadio()`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formradio) ViewHelper will automatically iterate through all of the possible ValueOptions.

Now the best way to handle your custom Markup would be to create your own implementation of the `FormMultiCheckbox` ViewHelper and overwrite the `renderOptions()` function with your custom template. You would then also need to write your own implementation of `FormRadio` which will extend your own `FormMultiCheckbox` and then you're done.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to assign more data to a form item? I want to be able to show A maps to Option A, but also that option A has a description of "A Description" next to it?

Comment: Well, in theory Form Elements could have HTML Attributes `longdesc` and basically all `data-foo` so that's where data could be stored and retrieved in your view like `echo $elem->getAttribute('data-foo')`, but I wonder if this is the best approach.

It could be a good thing to write your Form manually and just work yourself through with InputFilters, not using Zend\Form at all...